# I ve got a problem with my cart in the mobile devices. on desktop works

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I ve updated my theme and since then my cart on mobile didn t work . i select the product but nothing happens with the cart no display.
On the desktop version it works perfect . i ll attach here the error that appears on the inspect element console when i click on the shop icon.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at Object.V [as onLoad] (bottom-75f2ee243.js:233)
at bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at new t (bottom-75f2ee243.js:233)
at t.n.toggle (bottom-75f2ee243.js:233)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bottom-75f2ee243.js:233)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (bottom-75f2ee243.js:39)
at HTMLAnchorElement.g.handle (bottom-75f2ee243.js:39)
```

V @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
(anonymous) @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
t @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
n.toggle @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
(anonymous) @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:233
dispatch @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:39
g.handle @ bottom-75f2ee243.js:39

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYBUv.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO, you may want to start here [mcve]

Comment: Disable CCC for JS and you will find easily where is the error